# window.history.pushState doesnt navigate to where i want it

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

I am trying to make a navigation button that just sends me to the index page but shows a different text in the url.
so i found this line of code to help me do it.

> window.history.pushState("index.php", "test", "Testie");

But the problem is when i run it in an onclick function it just takes the last value and puts it in the url bar.
That itself is not the problem its that i dont have a Testie.html/php file.
I want it to be send to index.php but make the appearance of Testie in the url.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `history.pushState` is to say:

*Some other JavaScript has manipulated the page so what the user is seeing is the same as what they would see if they went to this URL*.

It lets you get fast updates to the page **and** bookmarkable URLs with real content that is good for fast initial page loads and for search engines to index.

It doesn't send data to the server (you need to do that with other code).

It **does** mean that if the URL isn't actually handled by the server (as you say it is in your case) then the page will break if the user does bookmark the page (or refreshes it, or sends the link to someone, etc).

---

If you want to navigate to a URL with Testie in it, then the first thing to do is to make the server support it. Forget about JavaScript.